# The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "EMP_SELF_KEY"

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have an employee table like this

```
 CREATE TABLE EMP (
   EMPNO int NOT NULL,
  ENAME VARCHAR(10),
 JOB VARCHAR(9),
MGR int CONSTRAINT EMP_SELF_KEY REFERENCES EMP (EMPNO),
HIREDATE DATE,
SAL int,
COMM int,
DEPTNO int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMP_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO),
CONSTRAINT EMP_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO));
```

and i tried to delete
employees with empno

```
 DELETE FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO =7566
```

but it's giving me an error like this:-

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE
> constraint "EMP_SELF_KEY". The conflict occurred in database
> "training", table "dbo.EMP", column 'MGR'. The statement has been
> terminated.

so what should I do to delete the employee?

fiddle link
[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9172170fbef8f5d352ba2906f95ef7f4)

Comment: the mgr column is a foreign key on the same table. you have to change the records with the `mgr = empno` or delete the records which are in the way.

Comment: what do you mean by changing the records with mgr=empno?...should i delete the employees who are mgr, is that what you are saying? can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean you could update the records which are referenced by the records you are trying to delete. For example, if you try to delete empno 7566 then you have to Update the records which are having mgr = 7566. e.g. `Update emp set mgr = 4711 where mgr = 7566`

Comment: but that also didnt wont work na..cause then also employee 7566 got another mgr but that didnt make it deletable...its still showing same error

Comment: Show us some sample data and the query that raises the error. (All as formatted text, no images.) Simplify! [mcve] Or/and create a fiddle that reproduces the error, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk.

Comment: yeah i added the fiddle ...please check

Comment: So, what do you want to happen to `FORD` and `SCOTT` who are currently managed by `JONES`? You have to ensure there are *no* references to `JONES` as a manager for *any* other employee.

Comment: assign another manager, anyone, with manager job ..